# Refreshing leaflet route without removing control

Tags: javascript, leaflet, osrm

I am trying to update the position of the user live and display a route from the current position to a final destination.

It all goes well, I refresh the position once every second but I can't make it work without removing the route control (this causes a flicker like effect)

What I do now is:

```
this.route = L.Routing.control({
                waypoints: [
                    L.latLng(e.latlng),
                    L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)
                ],
                routeWhileDragging: true
            }).addTo(this.map);
```

Once every second I call a function that does this:

```
 if (this.route) {

   // FIRST SOLUTION : this.map.removeControl(this.route)    
   //  this.route.setWaypoints([L.latLng(e.latlng),
   // L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)]);

   this.route.spliceWaypoints(0, 1, L.latLng(e.latlng));
}
```

First solution causes flickering while the second one doubles the markers.

Is there a way to remove / replace only one waypoints ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check.

```
if (this.map != undefined) {
  this.route.setWaypoints([L.latLng(33,44),L.latLng(34,45)]);
} else{
  this.loadMap();
  this.routing()
}
```